# Conditional ng-class on icon in table cell

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a table and using ng-repeat to bind my cells with the data.  One cell has edit, save, delete icons.  If an order has been posted then the delete/ save icons should be disabled and the icons also should be a different color.  I am able to disable the click event of the delete/save icons but can not figure out how to change the css class.  With this code the save and delete can not be clicked.  I'd like to turn them light gray or some obviously different color.

Here is the HTML:

```
       <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="order in vm.orders track by $index"  ng-dblclick="vm.editOrder(order)" style="cursor:pointer" ng-class="{'class':order.invoiceStatus, 'disabled-order': !order.invoiceStatus}">                                            
               <td ng-bind="(order.dtInvoiced | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' )"> </td>                                                
               <td ng-bind="order.invoiceNumber"></td>
               <td ng-bind="order.invoiceItems.mdbsPoNumber"></td>
               <td align="center" ng-bind="order.lines"></td>
               <td ng-bind="(order.total | number:2)"></td>
               <td align="center" ng-bind="order.carrier"></td>                                                
               <td>
                 <a ng-click="vm.editOrder(order)"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></i></a>
                 <a ng-click="order.disabledToggle || vm.saveOrder(order)"><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i></a>
                 <a ng-click="order.disabledToggle || vm.removeOrder(order)"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x link-icon"></i></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
```

Here is the JS to disable the click event of save and delete icons:

```
   function orderItems() {
    var orders;
    if (vm.Criteria != null) {
            orderService.getOrderData(vm.Criteria)
    .then(function (result) {
        vm.data = result.data;
        orders = vm.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.data.length; i++) {
            orders[i].disabledToggle = false;
            if (orders[i].invoiceStatus == "RCV") {
                orders[i].disabledToggle = true;                    
            }
            else {
                orders[i].disabledToggle = false;
            }
            vm.orders.push(orders[i]);                
        }

    });
    }
}
```

I've also tried in the icon:

```
<i ng-class="order.invoiceStatus = order.disabledToggle ? 'disabled-order class' : 'class' "></i>
```

Comment: I always refer to this article when using ng-class: https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass Hope it helps!

Comment: @mhodgesI saw that article glossed over it but found my answer near the bottom thanks

Comment: Great! You're welcome, glad it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class to evaluate a variable for true.  If the variable is true then a class selector will be injected into the element:

```
<a ng-click="order.disabledToggle || vm.saveOrder(order)"><i ng-class="{ 'cssCheckDisabled': jsCheckDisabled } class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i></a>
```

In this case we are evaluating jsCheckDisabled.  Once it is try the cssCheckDisabled class selector is injected into the element.

Then is as easy as making a class selector in your CSS to do what you want:

```
cssCheckDisabled {
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, just read the comments in the questions... Any way will leave the answer here.